# parsing a number comparison string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, math, eval

So I'm wondering if there is a simple method for, i guess, parsing a string that contains a number comparison.

For example I have a variable that contains a string like this
`str = "1>3";`

Right now I'm using the math plugin to use math.eval(str) which returns a boolean but I feel like this is an awfully big resource to include just for a simple comparison.

My script is currently like this, and I love the simplicity I just hate having to use such a big resource for it.

```
if (math.eval(str) == true) {
    //do something
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

Any input on this matter would be greatly appreciated. I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need that for friendly environment (non-public, no security considerations) you can use regular `eval` to compute result:

```
var result = eval("1>3");
```

Note that `eval` let you run any code and if you let user enter the "condition" and plan to use that for anything outside of personal calculator sample on you local machine - use proper parser that validates expressions and does not use arbitrary functions.

Comment: I seriously had no idea I could do this. I feel retarded. I'll try it out right now  and get back to you. thanks

Comment: Seriously thank you lol I'm kind of embarrassed -__-. Will accept as answer in 7 minutes when I'm allowed to. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you have such simple expressions, like

```
 expression := number comparison_operator number
 comparison_operator := < | > | = | ..
```

then it is also very simple to write a parser for this.

E.g. split the input string along the operator,

```
"1>3" -> 
op = ">" ->
split: ["1", "3"] -> 
num1_str = "1", num2_str = "3"
```

convert each number from its string representation to a number value.

```
num1 = 1, num2 = 3
```

Then apply the comparison operator.

```
switch (op) {
case "<":
  return num1 < num2;
case ">":
  return num1 > num2;
case "=":
  return num1 == num2;
// <=, >=, !=, ..
default:
  // unknown operator
}
```

Comment: This is such a wonderful answer. The only reason I didn't accept it is because I was really looking to keep the amount of lines needed similar to what I was using with math.eval and @Alexei Levenkov accomplished that for me. Still a great answer though and I thank you for taking the time to write this. I'm sure someone will get some help from this for sure.

Answer (score 0):

[This lib](https://github.com/silentmatt/expr-eval) does a lot of things out of the box for expression parsing.